# Interaction between peers in hyperledger fabric v2.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am a beginner in hyperledger fabric and currently working on the 2.3 version. I deployed the chaincode and my database is CouchDB. I have created identities for the wallet but I am confused about how should peer of org 2 can interact with it. because only the admin is able to access, not other's identities.

How they will interact with each other?

can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: You need clear information about creating an ID for your wallet.
Did you say that you performed the enroll command with admin information to Fabric-CA of Org2's organization?
Besides that, could you explain more clearly what you've done?.

Comment: @myeongkilkim I have created admin.id and appUser.id dor the peer0 in org1. And for creating the id of org2 I used the same method node entrollAdmin.js but for creating 2nd I don't know where to change the path so copied the identifies of org1 peer and deleted the folder wallet then I tried once again with org2. it created the same identities but I not able to use them couchdb1 and couchdb2

Comment: @myeongkilkim  if I login into the 1st database then the 2nd database gets logout. how can I deploy separately and how can peer1 from each org interact with each other. and peer.org.example has some port no. but that port refuses to connect. I am sorry it may be a simple question but I am totally new to technology.